# cx_Oracle Setting large value for CLOB var fails with cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-03146: Invalid buffer length for TTC field

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm attempting to set a very large value (>536MB) into a cx_oracle CLOB variable, but it appears to be failing around the 512MB mark.

```
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('foo/bar@baz')
cur = conn.cursor()
clob = cur.var(cx_Oracle.CLOB)

# The following is successful
clob.setvalue(0, 'A' * 1024 * 1024 * 511)

# The following fails
clob.setvalue(0, 'A' * 1024 * 1024 * 512)
```

The second command (or any value greater than this) fails with:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-03146: Invalid buffer length for TTC field
```

After making exactly three calls to the second command, the session itself appears to be disconnected (whereas this does not happen with the first command)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cx_Oracle.OperationalError: ORA-03135: connection lost contact
Process ID: 17567
Session ID: 137 Serial number: 9226
```

---

I've tested this on two environments with identical results: Python on my local environment connecting to my local Oracle; and python on a remote unix environment connecting to a different remote Oracle environment. Both of them fail at the exact same `1024 * 1024 * 512` line, which leads me to believe the issue may be with cx_Oracle.

Database version: Oracle 12CR1

Oracle Client version: 12.1.0.2.0

cx_Oracle version: Tested on 5.1.3 and 6.0.3 with identical results

Python version: 2.7.13

Everything is 64 bit.

---

My use case is that I need to call an PLSQL procedure to insert the CLOB into a database. Our project is following a specific ERP rule set and we are not allowed to do a direct DML. I have code similar to the following:

```
data = get_user_provided_data()

conn = cx_Oracle.connect('foo/bar@baz')
cur = conn.cursor()
clob = cur.var(cx_Oracle.CLOB)
clob.setvalue(0, data)

cur.callproc('xxfoo_bar_pkg.insert_one', 
               keywordParameters={
                   'p_data_i': clob, 
               })
```

Comment: You must likely have hit a bug here as a database connection should never just die, i.e. `ORA-03135: connection lost contact`. Can you also confirm your Oracle client version (the libraries that are loaded by the Python driver.

Comment: This is being followed up in https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/112   In general, if you're inserting via SQL into a LOB column, avoid temp LOBs so you don't use the temp table space. They also and don't have this issue.

Comment: @gvenzl I'm using 12.1.0.2.0 Oracle Client version

Comment: @ChristopherJones I've updated the bottom of my question to include a sample of the code I am using. We are using a PLSQL procedure to perform the actual insert (we are not allowed to make direct DMLs from python). Is there a way to avoid temp LOBs when calling `cur.callproc` ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Anthony Tuininga for his response over at the [github repo](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/112).

This apparently is a bug, but the following is an effective workaround, which involves changing the PLSQL to use an `OUT` param for the CLOB, and using Oracle's `empty_clob` to instantiate the value. This will return a [LOB locator](https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/2051.datatype-understanding-lob-locators) back to python, which is kind of like a pointer to the LOB value. You can write to the lob locator, followed by a commit, which will write the value to the DB. I'm not clear on the network implications of of this but the performance seems to be similar to

DDLs:

```
CREATE TABLE xxtest_cx_oracle (
    data CLOB
);


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE xxtest_cx_oracle_pkg
IS
    -- Normal way; limited to ~ 511MB
    PROCEDURE insert_one(
        p_data_i IN CLOB
    );

    -- Workaround; supports > 511MB
    PROCEDURE insert_one_workaround(
        p_data_o OUT CLOB
    );
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY xxtest_cx_oracle_pkg
IS 
    -- Normal way; limited to ~ 511MB
    PROCEDURE insert_one(
        p_data_i IN CLOB
    )
    IS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO xxtest_cx_oracle (
            data
        ) VALUES (
            p_data_i
        );
    END;

    -- Workaround; supports > 511MB
    PROCEDURE insert_one_workaround(
        p_data_o OUT CLOB
    )
    IS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO xxtest_cx_oracle (
            data
        ) VALUES (
            empty_clob()
        ) RETURNING data INTO p_data_o;
    END;
END;
```

Python:

```
import cx_Oracle
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('FOO/bar@BAZ')
cur = conn.cursor()

# Old way, using normal IN param; only supports ~511MB
data = cur.var(cx_Oracle.CLOB)
data.setvalue(0, 'A' * 1024 * 1024 * 511)
cur.callproc('xxtest_cx_oracle_pkg.insert_one', (data,))
conn.commit()

# New way using empty_clob and OUT param; supports > 511MB
data = cur.var(cx_Oracle.CLOB)
cur.callproc('xxtest_cx_oracle_pkg.insert_one_workaround', (data))
lob = data.getvalue()
lob.write('A' * 1024 * 1024 * 512)
conn.commit()
```

One thing I noticed was that attempting to close the `conn` would fail:

```
>>> cursor.close()
>>> conn.close()
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1054: connection cannot be closed when open statements or LOBs exist
```

But you can either just `del lob` or let `conn` go out of scope to resolve this.